# Manipulate data.frame with function

Tags: r, function, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe:

```
DF2 <- data.frame(column = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"), 
              start = c(2005,2001,2006,2005,2009), 
              end = c(2012,2009,2011,2010,2012), 
              stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and would like to create a function that does the following:

```
year.calcs <- function(x) {
          pre.5 <- x$start - 5
          pre.1 <- x$start - 1
          post.5 <- x$end + 5
          post.1 <- x$end + 1
}
```

so I could call:

```
year.calcs(DF2)
```

and add all of the new columns to the dataframe.

Comment: Just add this below the last line `cbind(x, pre.5, pre.1, post.5, post.1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method:

```
year.calcs <- function(x) {
  x[["pre.5"]] <- x$start - 5
  x[["pre.1"]] <- x$start - 1
  x[["post.5"]] <- x$end + 5
  x[["post.1"]] <- x$end + 1

  x
}

df <- year.calcs(x=DF2)
```

Which returns

```
> df
  column start  end pre.5 pre.1 post.5 post.1
1     C1  2005 2012  2000  2004   2017   2013
2     C2  2001 2009  1996  2000   2014   2010
3     C3  2006 2011  2001  2005   2016   2012
4     C4  2005 2010  2000  2004   2015   2011
5     C5  2009 2012  2004  2008   2017   2013
```